# Facebook app: permission not updating

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am making a facebook app for which i need permissions other than the basic permission. I have tried using scope as well as changing in the app settings, still I get only the basic permissions and no more other permissions. Below is the code :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
       FB.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response
    }, {scope:'user_photos,user_friends,friends_photos,user_status,publish_stream,user_photo_video_tags'});
    } else {
       FB.login(function(response) {
        // handle the response
        }, {scope:'user_photos,user_friends,friends_photos,user_status,publish_stream,user_photo_video_tags'});
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
});
</script>

<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that it takes some time for app permissions to propagate, but I have waited for hours. Any hint on whats going wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your code is not working and I am yet to try running it on my machine by I am posting a working code here. Please try using this code after following steps mentioned below

1. Create a new app on facebook.
2. In Permissions tab, select the user permissions that you want from user.
3. In code mentioned below, input your app id and try running it.

Code below is taken from http://hayageek.com/examples/oauth/facebook/oauth-javascript/index.php and is basic implementation of Javascript SDK.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXX', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://192.168.1.146/facebook/index.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
    {
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Connected to Facebook";
        //SUCCESS

    }    
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Failed to Connect";

        //FAILED
    } else 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>Logged Out";

        //UNKNOWN ERROR
    }
    }); 

    };

    function Login()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                getUserInfo();
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'user_photos'});


    }

  function getUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.username+"<br>";
          str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

    });
    }
    function getPhoto()
    {
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;

    });

    }
    function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: Hope this solves your problem, I will have a look at your tonight and explain what is going wrong with it.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. I tried to find why by comparing your code and mine and here is what was wrong with my code: I was using the fb login button. when using this i need to set data-perms="email,user_photos" in my html. So basically it becomes:
    <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" data-perms="email,user_photos" onclick="Login()"></fb:login-button>

Doing this change solves the problem. Thanks